# Queston on Resultant Vectors

Tags: vectors

There are specific equation for resultant vector base on their angle degree right ?
example : 2 vectors add together we get vector C = vector A + vector B

1. If the angle is 0 degrees we get $C = A + B + \cos0 = A + B$
2. If the angle is 30 degrees we get $C = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + 2AB\cos30}$
3. If the angle is 90 degrees we get $C = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + 2AB\sin90} = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2}$
4. If the angle is 180 degrees we get $C = \sqrt{$A^2 + B^2 + 2AB\cos180}$

if so how can you derive those equation ?

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Formula*: $$R^2 = P^2 + Q^2 + 2PQ\cos \theta$$
Where,

$R$ = Magnitude of resultant vector,

$P$ = Magnitude of vector P,

$Q$ = Magnitude of vector Q,

$\theta$ = Angle between two vectors

This formula is derived from the cosine rule. You can check the derivation of cosine rule from this [link](http://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/derivation-of-formulas/derivation-of-cosine-law).